# Delete node from singly LinkedList in a straightforward way

Tags: python, linked-list

I am learning LinkedList from an easy leetcode problem [Delete Node in a Linked List - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/delete-node-in-a-linked-list/)

> Write a function to delete a node (except the tail) in a singly linked list, given only access to that node.
>
> Given linked list -- head = [4,5,1,9], which looks like following:
>
> [image]
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> ```
> Input: head = [4,5,1,9], node = 5
> Output: [4,1,9]
> Explanation: You are given the second node with value 5, the linked list should become 4 -> 1 -> 9 after calling your function.
> ```
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> ```
> Input: head = [4,5,1,9], node = 1
> Output: [4,5,9]
> Explanation: You are given the third node with value 1, the linked list should become 4 -> 5 -> 9 after calling your function.
> ```
>
> **Note:**
>
> - The linked list will have at least two elements.
> - All of the nodes' values will be unique.
> - The given node will not be the tail and it will always be a valid node of the linked list.
> - Do not return anything from your function.

And the official solution:

Replace the value of the node you want to delete with the value in the node after it, and then delete the node after it.

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None

   class Solution:
        def deleteNode(self, node):
            """
            :type node: ListNode
            :rtype: void Do not return anything, modify node in-place instead.
            """
            node.val = node.next.val 
            node.next = node.next.next
```

I thought it cumbersome, so changed it to:

```
class Solution:
    def deleteNode(self, node):
        node= node.next
```

Assign the next node to the current node in a straightforward way

Unfortunately, it reports wrong answer.

I cannot figure out why it's not working.

The logic is free of bugs : the current node was shadowed by its next node,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what we want to do, delete `node`:

`pre -> node -> post`  => `pre -> post`

So what you should do is change `pre.next` from `node` to `node.next`. like:

`pre.next = node.next`

If you do `node = node.next`, it only change the `node` reference.

It has no any effect on original ListNode.

But we can not get `pre` in this scenario, so we have to change `node` value to become to `post`, and remove `post`.

Hope that helps you, and comment if you have further questions. : )

Comment: I got it.node is an object. cannot do something like `[1, 2, 3] = [3, 4, 5]`, cos both sides are objects rather than variable.